# When click button, application database crashes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have created a database app, which will allow the user to search through a database of films. My understanding is that when the search button is clicked it should call the search method to check the database entries and return an entry that matches the search term, but upon clicking the button it crashes the app, any help and explanation would be appreciated. It would also be great to confirm that the database is being created, thanks

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        public final static String FILM = "com.mnt.filmapp6.FILM";
        protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnAddFilm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_film);
        Button btnFavourite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favourites);

        btnAddFilm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity3.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        }
        );
    }

    public void search(View v){
        EditText edtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
        String search = "%" + edtSearch.getText().toString() + "%";
        db = new DbHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
        String[] tblColumns = {"*"};
        String where = "film LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {search, search, search, search};
        Cursor results = db.query("FILMTABLE", tblColumns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
        films(results);
    }

    public void films (Cursor c){

        int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("film");
        int directorIndex = c.getColumnIndex("director");
        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        String title = c.getString(titleIndex);
        String director = c.getString(directorIndex);
        int filmID = c.getInt(idIndex);

        TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        txt.setId(filmID);
        txt.setText(title + ", " + director);
        txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt.setTextSize(15);
        //txt.setText(ScrollView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Dbhelper

```
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                  FILM + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        ACTOR + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        ACTOR2 + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        DIRECTOR + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        DESCRIPTION + "TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

        Cursor countRows = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM FILMTABLE", null);
        countRows.moveToFirst();
        int NumRows = countRows.getInt(0);
        countRows.close();

        if (NumRows == 0) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("film", "Wolf of Wall Street");
            values.put("actor", "Leonardo Dicaprio");
            values.put("actor2", "Jonah Hill");
            values.put("director", "Martin Scorses");
            values.put("description", "True story of New York stockbroker Jordan Belfort. From the American dream to corporate greed, Belfort goes from penny stocks and righteousness to IPOs and a life of corruption in the late 80's.");
            db.insert("FILMTABLE", null, values);
            values.clear();

            values.put("film", "Captain Philips");
            values.put("actor", "Tom Hanks");
            values.put("actor2", "Catherine Keener");
            values.put("director", "Paul Greengrass");
            values.put("description", "True story, Captain Phillips is a multi-layered examination of the 2009 hijacking of the U.S. container ship Maersk Alabama by a crew of Samali pirates.");
            db.insert("FILMTABLE", null, values);
            values.clear();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Main activty xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/film_app" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtSearch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="search"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_film"
    android:id="@+id/add_film"
    android:layout_below="@+id/favourites"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/search"
    android:onClick="add"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/favourites"
    android:id="@+id/favourites"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="favourite"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
    android:hint="Enter Film/Actor/Director"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/resultLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Logcat

```
03-04 12:16:53.829    1879-1879/com.mnt.filmapp6 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mnt.filmapp6, PID: 1879
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: film (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM FILMTABLE WHERE film LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
        at com.mnt.filmapp6.MainActivity.search(MainActivity.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
 ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
          FILM + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                ACTOR + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                ACTOR2 + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DIRECTOR + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DESCRIPTION + "TEXT NOT NULL);"
);
```

It should be like this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
          FILM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                ACTOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                ACTOR2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DIRECTOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
);
```

Comment: I used your code but I'm still getting the same error back.

Comment: @MNT Because `onCreate` is not called as long as you have the old database file.

Comment: Yes, try recreating the database (delete old one, and use this new code to create a new one).

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
>   film (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM FILMTABLE WHERE film
>   LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?

Check your database table `FILMTABLE` for `film` column. I think `film` column not present in your database table or SQL syntax is wrong.

Try to run your query first on database by using any client and then use it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: film (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM FILMTABLE WHERE film LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?
```

Check your Table and SQL Syntax for `film` column.

Before posting in Stack Overflow, have a detailed analysis of `Logs`.

Comment: I have done but can't seem to find the problem within the code posted above.

Comment: Your actual problem was fixed by @miselking. Please have a detailed look at his answer.

Comment: I have used this code but I am still getting the same error.